# Deploy PythonAnywhere

Tags: python, django, github

I built my Django project on my local PC and then I 'uploaded' all the files to GitHub. For using PythonAnywhere as a clone to GitHub, I thought all the files wouldn't be transfered to PythonAnywhere server, but for my surprise they all gone there.

In this way, I have now 3 different locals to get my files stored: local PC, GitHub and PythonAnywhere.

When I make changes in my code (PC), I'll have to commit to GitHub and then update to PythonAnywhere?

Is that all right or I'm missing something?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

1. commit on your local machine
2. push to github
3. pull on PythonAnywhere
4. run `./manage.py migrate` if needed
5. reload your web app on PythonAnmywhere "web" page

Comment: Thank you for your answer but my issue is about concept and not coding. As I said, I would have 3 different drives to store my files: PC, GitHub and PythonAnywhere. Is that all right ou should I have only 2 locals? What is usual in this process?

Comment: Three locations is the normal setup.  You could set things up to push directly from your PC to PythonAnywhere, but it's a bit harder to manage, and when you're getting started just doing push locally to GitHub and then pull from GitHub to PythonAnywhere is easier to do.